# Codekit 2.0.5 Not Recognizing Compass

Tags: susy-compass, codekit, susy-sass

I have been pulling what hair I have left out. I just downloaded Codekit this week and want to redesign my own site using Compass/SASS/Susy. I have tried several ways to get it to work, the preference in Codekit to point at the executable path. I am really excited to get started on this new endeavor, but I can't seem to get by the setup. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is your project set up correctly? Susy 2 requires SASS 3. CodeKit 2 has an option to use libSASS instead of SASS (I use it). There are other dependencies for which I use Bundler. If you use Bundler to set up your project, it will add 'require 'compass/import-once/activate' to your config.rb. Other than that, there is no specific need to require or import compass. Do you have a CodeKit error message that you can post to let us see what is going wrong?

I assume that you are using Susy 2. If you are using Susy 1 you must add @import "susyone"; to your config.rb. But I expect you know that already.

Comment: All I am getting is this message.

Compass was unable to compile one or more files in the project: 

You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.

Comment: I think the issue I am having is the config.rb file. There is very little documentation or a sample I could use to get up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

Re your comments:

Using Bundler, my Gemfile includes:

```
gem "susy", "~>2.1.0"
gem "sass", "~>3.3.0"
gem "breakpoint", "~>2.4.0"
```

so these must be installed on your system accessible to susy. CodeKit doesn't need compass but my config.rb file includes these:

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
require 'breakpoint'
require 'sassy-buttons'
```

obviously you may not be using sassy-buttons.

The documentation for Susy2 is extensive and is available at http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/.  You don't say how you set up your project, but I assume that your CodeKit setup points to the correct files from SCSS to compiled CSS.

You need to '@import susy' in one of your .scss files. (I'm not sure that that is necessary anymore).